# Svelte with DaisyUI Modal not opening after promise is resolved

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, daisyui

I've got a modal which is supposed to open when a link is clicked:

```
<script>
    import AddressForm from "../forms/AddressForm.svelte";

    let openModal = false;
    let formData = {};

const showModal = async () => {
        const id = "bb80b8f9-1de8-431c-9b07-421e462d59e4";
        openModal = true;
}
</script>

<div class="flex justify-center">
    <a href="#address-modal" on:click={showModal}>
       <span class="align-middle edit-color">Edit</span>
    </a>
</div>

{#if openModal}
    <h1>Test Ttitle</h1>
<div class="modal" id="address-modal">
    <div class="modal-box relative w-11/12 max-w-5xl">
        <label for="address-modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-circle absolute right-2 top-2">✕</label>
        <AddressForm
                formData={formData}
                isModal={true}
        />
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

The code above works fine, when the link is clicked the modal appears. But now I've gotta send some data to the component loaded in the modal, to do so I'm making a call within `showModal` to a function that returns a promise. After the promise is resolved the modal is not opening:

```
const showModal = async () => {
        // console.log('opening modal')
        const id = "bb80b8f9-1de8-431c-9b07-421e462d59e4";
        let address = await getAddress(id)
        console.log(address)
        formData = address;
        openModal = true;
    }
```

with the code above the modal does not open. I tried the following as well:

```
const showModal = async () => {
        // console.log('opening modal')
        const id = "bb80b8f9-1de8-431c-9b07-421e462d59e4";

        let address = await getAddress(id)
            .then(address => {
                console.log(address)
                formData = address;
                openModal = true;
            });
}
```

but the result is the same.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you stepped through the function? Is `openModal = true` ever reached?

Comment: Would you try implementing an {#await getAdress() then formData} block nested within an {#if openModal} block ?

Comment: @H.B. yes, it is reached.

Comment: @Tonton-Blax cannot do that, the call to `getAddress` should be invoked when the link is clicked, if I add an `#await getAddress()` then the modal will be opened when the page loads and since I've got multiple instances of that component we would be making multiple calls to the server with no need. It must be called on demand